# Vim replacing spaces with tabs on copy

Tags: windows, vim, tabs, copy-paste

I have a code buffer in vim with lines that are prefixed with spaces (already did `:set expandtab` and `:retab`).  Now I select some or all of the lines and copy them to the Windows clipboard.  When I subsequently paste into another app, the spaces at the beginnings of all the lines have been replaced with tabs.

I can reproduce this pasting into several other applications, so I'm pretty sure it's vim doing the replacing.  Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried what you described, and I got spaces in the other applications -- not tabs. `expandtab` should be enough, but here's my (somewhat, but not all completely,) relevant vrmc settings. Maybe one will work for you:

```
set nocompatible
behave mswin
set shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
set cindent
set smartindent
set autoindent
set expandtab
```

Comment: I set the couple of those that I didn't have already and that seemed to do the trick.  Not sure which is one is the "magic" setting.